# Columns switched when writing to CSV in raspberry pi

Tags: python, json, csv, raspberry-pi

I am calling the DarkSky API and writing the data to a csv. On my Windows, it copies the information in order of the data keys (keys are in the comment line after try)

On the RPI it copies the data but it switches the order of the columns.

For example:

On my windows the first csv row is: time, summary, icon, nearest...

On the RPI the first row would be: precipIntensity, icon...

**What am I doing wrong?**

CODE:

```
import time
import requests
import csv
import json

try:

# 'time', 'summary', 'icon', 'nearestStormDistance', 'nearestStormBearing', 'precipIntensity', 'precipProbability', 'temperature', 'apparentTemperature', 'dewPoint', 'humidity', 'pressure', 'windSpeed', 'windGust', 'windBearing', 'cloudCover', 'uvIndex', 'visibility', 'ozone'

        while 1:
            URL =url
            r=requests.get(URL)
            data=r.json()

            csvrow=[]
            for k in data['currently'].keys():
                if k=='time':
                    csvrow.append(time.strftime("%D %H:%M", time.localtime(int(data['currently']['time']))))
                else:
                    csvrow.append(data['currently'][k])

            with open('Weather Project CSV', mode='a') as wpj:
                wpj = csv.writer(wpj, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                wpj.writerow(csvrow)
            time.sleep(10)
except:
    print('Error Encountered')
    #turn on LED
```

OUTPUT:

*RPI first row:*

`Clear,-0.31,3.11,clear-day,111,15.27,230,03/08/19 11:49,435.84,-3.97,257,3,0,-12.06,0.23,1027.93,0,4.65,0.41`

*Windows first row:*

`03/08/19 11:58,Partly Cloudy,partly-cloudy-day,109,256,0,0,-0.19,-3.84,-11.91,0.41,1027.76,3.13,4.72,229,0.27,3,15.13,434.52`

Comment: At a guess, you have different versions of python, one being less than 3.6 where dictionaries don't have order

Comment: I think @roganjosh is probably right. To make sure that the dictionary is always ordered, use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) — which would work whether or not the core `dict` maintains order (even though technically it's not necessary when it does). You could also check `sys.version_info` to determine whether it's needed or not.

Comment: There is no guarantee tha the `json` will maintain column order. Swicht to `csv.DictWriter`, there is a parameter `fieldnames=` which defines the column order.

Comment: You were all right about the dictionary order. I ended up just iterating tthrough a list of the keys, because I already knew exactly which keys I wanted. Thanks!